# unclosed string literal error at compile time because it contains double quotes and pre tags of HTML

Tags: java, string

In my program, there is a string that contains double quotes and less than and greater than symbols. Here is a sample String:

```
String s2="div class=\"codeblock\"><pre name=\"code\" class=\"java\" ";
```

Can anyone help me?

Comment: You need to escape the double quotes:`"some string with \"double quotes\" in the middle"`.

Comment: `"\""` (please do your research before posting here)

Comment: I have replaced all the double quotes by \" but it gives error!

Comment: Source code is String s2="div class=\"codeblock\"><pre name=\"code\" class=\"java\"
";

Comment: @Sonno Jaiswal------ Edit your post and paste your source code there and not in comments.

Answer (score 1):

Escaping "\" is the answer. Alternatively as lots of escaping required in xml (html can also be treated as xml), it would be a good idea to have a separate file and read the string from the file.

Answer (score -1):

Thanks Everyone, I finally find out the solutions, I copied the double quotes from the html file, so there was the problem. When I changed the double quote in java file, it compiled successfully.

Comment: Thats why I said it compiles successfully