# JSON not reading escape symbols from DB

Tags: java, json, spring-data-jpa

So, I got values from DB `@Table` that contains column with String value and json in it. But as I try to map it with `ObjectMapper.writeValueAsString()` all i get is this (Also implying that those escape symbols as backward slashes are in a string):

`\"list\" [ \"key\":\"value\", ...  , \"key\":\"value\"] }`

It also appears that `@Entity` class have other fields as that table columns, but they seem to map okay, without escape symbols inside a String

Any idea why that happens? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
String yourJson = "{Key:\\'aa'}";
String a = yourJson.replace("\\","");
System.out.println(a);
```

Similar: 
[unclosed string literal error at compile time because it contains double quotes and pre tags of HTML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14709700/unclosed-string-literal-error-at-compile-time-because-it-contains-double-quotes)

Comment: Thanks for answer, but it actually would help if a string from a db was parcing that way, which is actually not the case.
I'll make an answer with the situation that went for me in a few days